# Should we include a macro(#define) in both .h & .cpp files

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

If i use them in both the files. 
Going with the term "macro" in c++ it's just a replacement mechanism(doesn't know anything about c++ structure) that happens in pre-compilation stage.

Is this the reason that i should define macro(#define) in both the files or doesn't need to do that or am i missing anything.?

Comment: You need to understand, what a [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) is. Reading [phases of translation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) is probably also helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Defining the macro in the .h file and then just including that .h file in the .cpp file is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Assume a simple case first. You have the .cpp file using the .h file:

- Car.cpp
- Car.h

If you have a constant, say: `#define KM_PER_MINUTE 3`. If this constant is used by any function inside the .h file, put this #define in the .h file:

```
Inside Car.h:
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H
... 
#define KM_PER_MINUTE 3
...
int calculate_total_KM(int minute) 
{
    return minute * KM_PER_MINUTE;
}
...
#endif
```

On the other hand, if this constant is used only in the .cpp file, put this #define in the .cpp file:

```
Inside Car.cpp:
#define KM_PER_MINUTE 3
...
int calculate_total_KM(int minute) 
{
    return minute * KM_PER_MINUTE;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace):

> The #define directives define the identifier as macro, that is instruct the compiler to replace all successive occurrences of identifier with replacement-list, which can be optionally additionally processed. **If the identifier is already defined as any type of macro, the program is ill-formed unless the definitions are identical.**

I guess it fully replies to your question.
It goes without saying that you can define a macro in a .h file, then include it wherever you need that macro.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in `#ifndef` then it doesn't matter, it will be included only once (the first occurrence). I you doesn't, then you'll get warning for already defined macro when the macro defined in the source and also the header with the macro included.

BTW: There is a third place, you can declare the macro in the makefile, or project settings.

Comment: You **might** get a warning. It's legal to have two definitions of a macro if they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

'define macro(#define) in both the files' cause redefinition error or warning.
It's not good. It may cause program compile error(good thing), or runtime error(terrible thing).